# Joomla. Read more

Tags: php, joomla, cms

CMS Joomla использую впервые, поэтому возникли проблемы. В редакторе Tinymce сохраняю длинный текст, но он обрезается на половину. После недолгих ковыряний я понял, что в базе данных текст делится на две части. Так вот, как убрать это самое деление? Или где найти функцию деления, чтоб указать количество символов до деления?

Версия Joomla! - Joomla! 3.6.5 Stable.

Знаков с пробелами - 90 000

P.S. Как я понимаю на сайте создан модуль `mod_custom2` и через него на сайт выводится этот код из 90000 символов.

Файл `mod_custom2.xml`:

```
<files>
    <filename module="mod_custom2">mod_custom2.php</filename>
</files>
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="options" label="COM_MODULES_BASIC_FIELDSET_LABEL">
            <field
                name="code"
                label="code"
                description="code"
                type="editor"
                filter="safehtml"
                editor="none"
            />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Comment: какая версия Joomla? сколько символов в этом "Длинном тексте" ? По стандарту редактор ничего не обрезает в тексте

Comment: Текст какого объема?

Comment: @Arsen правил текст

Comment: впервые слышу о mod_custom2, знаю только mod_custom, т.е вы данный текст не в материалах сохраняете а в модуле?

Comment: @Arsen, мне кажется это одно и то же. Да, текст хранится в модуле. Текст вводится в editor

Comment: mod_custom2 - такого модуля не должно быть в линейке Joomla, если вы используйте какой-то самописный модуль то трудно понять что там происходит. В базе даных где сохраняется контент из редактора модуля имеет тип 'mediumtext' который имеет значение в длину  16 мил символов... т.е проблем с базой не должно быть , возможно именно в модуле происходит обрезание текста, ещё раз проверьте какой вы модуль используете ?

Comment: @Arsen, в /modules/mod_custom2 всего 2 файла, php-ный файл вообще пустой, xml файл добавил в основной текст

Comment: а /modules/mod_custom2 - это вы в дириктории админки смотрите ? или всё таки в папке модулей в фронтенде?  
administrator/modules/mod_custom2  или /modules/mod_custom2 ?

Comment: @Arsen, именно /modules/mod_custom2, в корневом каталоге. В папке administrator/modules/ нету папки mod_custom2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56979/discussion-between-arsen-and-zakiroof).